# Where is the "enable automatic sigin" on Xcode 8?

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I'm looking for "Automatic signin" checkbox field, but I cannot find it. It's my first experience with Xcode 8. May you help me to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should help you:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1814/_index.html
http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev23aab79b4

you just need to select your project and tell xcode to "Automatically manage signing".